# How to intercept audio/video streaming requests in ASP.NET web server based on IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm trying to convert from a Silverlight-based media player to an HTML5/Javascript implementation on an ASP.NET website using MVC on a home-based webserver using IIS Express on Windows 8.1.

The player needs to support playing segments within the media file, meaning I need the ability to seek in the file by setting currentTime on the audio or video element and using a timeout to stop the playback (since using an ontimeupdate handle proved too flaky to stop at the right time).  The problem is supporting the multiple file formats required by the different browsers.  Rather than preconverting everything, I opted to implement a "/ConvertCheck?path=/media/file.ogg&type=audio/ogg" action that returns a file buffer, doing a lazy conversion if the file doesn't exist yet in the given format, but does in another supported format.  This works okay with IE and FireFox, but on Chromium, seeking using the currentTime property doesn't work.  It does work on IE and FireFox though.

Effectively I set up an audio or video element like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="/ConvertCheck?path=/media/file.mp3&type=audio/mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="/ConvertCheck?path=/media/file.ogg&type=audio/ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the media formats avaliable.
</audio>
```

Is there an API in MVC and ASP.NET that would let my action set up the proper streaming of the media file that would work with Chromium, and is easy enough for a novice like me to use?  Or is there a simpler way to do the interception and lazy conversion?  Otherwise I might just have to have the server convert the media files whenever the initial page references just one of them, rather than trigger the conversion when the actual format is needed.

I'm wishing Microsoft would just support Silverlight everywhere, as my Silverlight-based player both works and looks a lot better.

Thanks.

-John